# Server client send and receive doesn't work

Tags: c, unix, udp

I'm trying to create server and client through examples,
I saw an example online and tried to make the same, but it didn't work for me and I don't understand why.

Server

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int socket_fd, cc, fsize;
  struct sockaddr_in  s_in, from;
  struct { char head; u_long  body; char tail;} msg;
  char name[10];

  socket_fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  bzero((char *) &s_in, sizeof(s_in)); 

  s_in.sin_family = (short)AF_INET;
  s_in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    
  s_in.sin_port = htons((u_short)0x3333);
  fflush(stdout);    
  bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_in, sizeof(s_in));

  for(;;) {
    fsize = sizeof(from);
    recvfrom(socket_fd,name,sizeof(name),0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fsize);
    printf("Got data : %s",name);
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Client

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int socket_fd;   //creating 1 int
  struct sockaddr_in  dest;   
  struct hostent *hostptr;    
  struct { char head; u_long body; char tail; } msgbuf;  
  char name[10];
  socket_fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);  
  bzero((char *) &dest, sizeof(dest)); 
  hostptr = gethostbyname(argv[1]);   
  dest.sin_family = (short) AF_INET;   
  bcopy(hostptr->h_addr, (char *)&dest.sin_addr,hostptr->h_length); 
  dest.sin_port = htons((u_short)0x3333);   

  printf("Enter your name: ");
  scanf("%s",name);

  printf("%s",name);
  sendto(socket_fd,name,sizeof(name),0,(struct sockaddr *)&dest,sizeof(dest));
  return 0; 
}
```

Can someone explain my problem?

Comment: Is that you miss a `*/` at the end of `/* They say you must do this`

Comment: its not the problem
it didnt copy it well

Comment: yes, but suggest you to add it for the correct code.

Comment: What are your inputs & what outputs you get?

Answer (score 1):

NUL-terminate your buffer:

```
int n;
...
n = recvfrom(socket_fd,name,sizeof(name),0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fsize);
if (n == -1) {
    perror("recvfrom");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
name[n] = '\0';
printf("Got data : %s",name);
...
```

Also note that `bzero` and `bcopy` are deprecated, use `memset` and `memmove`

Comment: Care should be taken when doing this, as [`recvfrom`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/recvfrom.html) *can* return `-1` on error, and the resulting follow-up assignment will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: it's still not working 
i think it doesnt get into the server loop for some reason